# Best server hypervisor that can be managed through a MAC

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, mac

I have a HP microserver gen 8 which I want to install a hypervisor on so I can install and run multiple VMs from remotely. I only have a MAC to use for administration, any ideas of good hyperVisors for this.

I looked into ESXi, Hyper-V and XenServer but they are all windows centric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about "enterprise" grade virtualization solutions, in my opinion, you won't find any other hypervisors which offer that kind of level.

Since current ESXi platform are still web-based with regards to management I'd say you could go for that, or run a Hyper-V environment and manage it through parallels.

It's not the most streamlined solution for what you want I would imagine, but then again (and I'm not going to be making friends with this statement), when it comes down to IT Infrastructure MacOS isn't the most suited (from personal experience). Especially in a Wintel environment.

Comment: VMWare 6.5 will have an HTML5 client integrated into the vCenter Server appliance.